# Table structure not creating properly from base class in EF code first MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a DB set models which inherit from base class model as Below.

Base Class:

```
 public abstract  class BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public int AddedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Child Class:

```
public class AccountType : BaseModel
    {
        //[Key]
        //public int Account_Type_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Account_Type_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Account_Type_Code { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string AccountType_Description { get; set; }

    }
```

And my DBContext is as below:

```
 public class BankApplicationContext :DbContext
    {
        public BankApplicationContext() : base("BankContextEntities")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new BankApplicationIntializer());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<BaseModel> BaseModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>().ToTable("BaseModel");
            modelBuilder.Entity<AccountType>().ToTable("AccountType");
        }

    }
```

When the Database is created the table looks like this

[image]

[image]

But i need all the Audit columns from base class generated in child class as below:

**AccountType:**

Id (PK of Account Type)

AccountTypeName

AccountTypeCode

AccountTypeDescription

IsActive

ModifiedBy

ModifiedDate

AddedBy

AddedDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For supertypes like this, don't map them in the database at all.  You don't really want the ability to query the database for all BaseModel types of any subtype, as they aren't not the same entity, and are not substitutable in any business logic.

Instead just delete the `DbSet<BaseModel>` property from your DbContext, and each BaseModel entity subtype will separately map and store the inherited properties.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [Table per Concrete Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) structure.

But here is the problem: this only works for non-abstract classes.

If we assume that `BaseModel` is not abstract, you can change your table mapping to include the inherited properties:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>().Map(m => {
        m.ToTable("BaseModel");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<AccountType>().Map(m => {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("AccountType");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Georg , getting this error "The type 'AccountType' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting. "

Comment: I see. I think the problem is caused because we try to map the abstract BaseModel. Do you need to access the abstract entity? Else you could only map `AccountType`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540976/multiple-inheritance-with-entity-framework-tpc